# How do I remove the pixel size limitation on ImageMagick?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have ImageMagick on my webserver processing images that are uploaded but it seems to have a limitation of 4000 pixels and it'll error out. How do I remove that limitation?

Currently my LimitRequestBody is at 536870911 (500mb)

I also have these set:

ini_set('max_file_uploads',150);
ini_set('memory_limit','64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','6M');
ini_set('max_execution_time',240);
ini_set('post_max_size','8M');
ini_set('max_input_time',240);

Comment: Are you sure it's a size limitation and not a memory limitation or hard drive space limitation (it creates large temp files)?

Comment: if you know the exact error message, grep for it in the source, and edit the offending code?

Comment: I have more then enough ram + HD space. That can't be it. The strangest thing is that it doesn't throw an error in php. I just get an HTTP error in my uploader. Screenshot: http://cl.ly/1E3I0C0s3G1s2J1M2I3v

Answer (score 2):

Check your `MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT` environment variable:

> Set the maximum width * height of an image that can reside in the pixel cache memory.

Also check the `MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT` environment variable:

> Set maximum amount of disk space in bytes permitted for use by the pixel cache. When this limit is exceeded, the pixel cache is not be created and an error message is returned.

You might be able to change the amount of memory you're using by upping the limit, using the `-limit memory <xx>` command line option.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. Looking into that now. I'd also like to add this: The odd thing is the file can be 900kb or 8mb, as long as the resolution is larger then 4000 pixels, thats when it errors out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's ImageMagik?  I've used ImageMagik with some very large files before and had no problems.  It could be something set in your web configuration (max file size uploaded).

If running apache check your httpd.conf

In httpd.conf add or check for this line
LimitRequestBody

Increase filesize to something that makes sense for your application.

Comment: Right now I have this set for LimitRequestBody: 536870911. The odd thing is the file can be 900kb or 8mb, as long as the resolution is larger then 4000 pixels, thats when it errors out.